# How to use same object with its value in different class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Here i have a method `getAWSCredential` which returns `cred` with some value in it.

```
@Override
    public AWSCredentialDTO getAWSCredential(String user_name) {
        AWSCredentialDTO cred= (AWSCredentialDTO) entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from aws_user_credentials a where a.user_name=:userName",AWSCredentialDTO.class)
        .setParameter("userName", user_name).getSingleResult();
        return cred;

    }
```

Here I have one more service `ec2` where I need to make use of values returned in `cred` in previous method.

```
private AmazonEC2 ec2;

    public AmazonEC2 ec2() {
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(aws_access_key_id,
                aws_secret_access_key);
        return AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).build();
    }
```

Both the above methods are separate classes. First I will run the `getAWSCredential` and then I will invoke `ec2` where I need to make use of the values of `cred`.  Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this?
This is a spring boot application.

Comment: Did u try serialization

Comment: How to do that @Gundamaiah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate class say `ClassCred` and create an object for `ClassCred` within the same class `ClassCred credObj = new ClassCred()`. Get the `credObj` from `getAWSCredential(String user_name)` method and set the `cred` returned by `getAWSCredential` method to `credObj`. Now the object `credObj` hass the value `cred` returned by `getAWSCredential` method. Now from your `ec2()` method you can invoke the `credObj` and get the values stored in it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'd like to use DependencyInjection for it if the credentials are global or on a context, you can create a bean that either stores the credentials or the EC2 instance as a proxy to access it within the context of the session of the user.

Please specify if you have a single username/password or you've got multiple and the different requests need to be served using a username or another.

If you've got a single, you can create an API Key and set it in `application.properties`. You can use `cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey` and `cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey`.

Comment: I think this is a better answer, please post some code for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a spring bean of the class containing `getAWSCredential` and autowire it in the class which needs it. Check the sample code below.

```
@Component
public class AmazonUtil {
    ...

    @Override
    public AWSCredentialDTO getAWSCredential(String user_name) {
        AWSCredentialDTO cred= (AWSCredentialDTO) entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from aws_user_credentials a where a.user_name=:userName",AWSCredentialDTO.class)
        .setParameter("userName", user_name).getSingleResult();
        return cred;
    }
}

@Component
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    private AmazonUtil amazonUtil;

    public AmazonEC2 ec2(String userName) {
        AWSCredentialDTO credsDto = amazonUtil.getAWSCredential(userName);

        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = ...construct using credsDto

        return AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: But in this case, i will consume ec2() method from various other class like Test.ec2(); So I don't think your solution will workout

Comment: Same thing will have to be done, `Test` is a `spring-bean` so it can be injected to other classes as field, just like `AmazonUtil` has been injected in it.

Comment: That, or he uses a singleton ;-) but whatever, I think you are on the right track here.

Comment: I think answer by Alex Roig is better one, as that's the way to go in `spring-boot`, if spring supports AWS autoconfiguration and OP has a single pair of username/password then there's no need to do all this.

Comment: @GhostCat if we try to create our own singleton then we will have to take care of creating dependencies and in turn transitive dependencies as well. Like in this case `AmazonUtil` is dependent on `entityManager`.